# Highcharts - the third line is not displayed properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, highcharts

I have a Highcharts graph that consist of 3 lines - [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hHJvq/). The problem is, that the third line (the black one - **New York**) is not displayed properly - the points with 0 value are not shown into the graph.

But the zero-points for those 2 previous  lines are displayed properly.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [0, 5.68, 0, 0, 2.55, 0, 0, 0]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
        }]
    });
});
```

Am I missing something or why is the third line incomplete?

Thanks

Comment: Please always include your code in the question. A fiddle is great, but if the site goes down your question becomes unanswerable.

Comment: Also, your graph is working correctly with all data plotted. The issue is because the first 3 points of `New York` data are hidden behind the data for `Berlin`

Comment: Oh yea, I am just testing it and the `Berlin` data overlaying `New York` - sorry for "pointless" question.